# Incorrect url for sharing blog on linkedin

Tags: 404-error, plugin-jetpack

I have a self-hosted Wordpress blog with Jetpack installed.
My Wordpress URL structure is

> http://mydomain.com/archives/%postname%.

Using the Jetpack's Publicize feature, I connected my blog to my LinkedIn profile.

New posts now automatically appear on LinkedIn, however, the post's URL appearing on LinkedIn inherits the following structure:

> http://mydomain.com/2013/06/24/%postname%

which of course gives a 404 error.

Any suggestions on how to correct this problem?

Comment: Did you try refreshing permalinks?

Comment: Can you follow `Settings` > `Permalinks` and check if your custom structure is there, then click the **Save Changes** button once. It will refresh your permalinks structure in your database.

Answer (score 0):

These Jetpack settings are stored on WordPress.com. You can refresh them by refreshing permalinks as @GhostToast suggested. You can also force an update of your Jetpack settings by going to the Jetpack menu in your dashboard, and disconnecting then reconnecting to WordPress.com.